# What are the odds of successfully re-entering the UK after previously having stayed there on a Tier 2 visa?

Tags: visas, uk, denial-of-entry, new-zealand-citizens

Will I have issues re-entering the UK for Christmas, after being on a Tier 2 visa three months prior?

I lived in the UK throughout 2017 with a Tier 2 visa until deciding to ask for a transfer back to NZ with my company. My last day of work was mid-Sept/17 and I left the UK to NZ the next day. I started work the next week. I previously had 2 UK visa before this, never overstayed, never had a visa rejected.

I promised my friend that I'd celebrate Christmas with her and her husband in London so I booked a week-long ticket from 24th to Jan 1st. I heard stories from other Kiwis about being denied at the border so I want to be fully-prepared. These are the documents I'm planning on bringing:

- Flight Itinerary + Receipt Invoice (Inbound and Return)
- Hotel Booking + Receipts
- Heathrow Train Booking Receipt
- Letter of Resignation from UK Employer + confirmation that they'll cancel my visa;
- Letter of Employment from NZ Employer
- NZ Bank Statements
- NZ Rental Application

Nothing left in the UK apart from a bank account - still have my BRP but will leave that home.

I also tried to apply for Standard Visa online but for some reason, I can't do so using my name / date of birth which worries me.

Comment: As long as you're honest and have nothing to hide I wouldn't worry, you have ties to your home country with your job and have a valid reason for coming back. If the border guard is concerned as a last resort they might call the people you are coming to spend Christmas with to see if they confirm your story. Not putting it as an answer because as always it is down to the border guards discretion. Even if you got a visitor visa its basically the same at the border, plus being denied a visa is worse than being denied at the border